# Upgrade property sheets to Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I updated my Visual Studio 2005 solution to Visual Studio 2010. I used property sheets (*.vsprops) to configure my projects. After upgrade, it updated all the *.vsprops to the new *.props. However, the new property sheets are just empty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

</Project>
```

So I guess that Visual Studio migration wizard doesn't support upgrading the property sheets. It's reasonable to upgrade them by hand (about 20 sheets). Yet, my question is: Do you know some utility or a simpler method to do this?

Comment: In my case some property sheets were empty while others were not; I updated all of them by hand.. can't live without them ;P
edit: also note that the evaluation order is completely diffrent, this can cause a lot of problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .vsprops -> .props conversion is really shoddy, looks like it was hacked together by some intern. It will surely break when you're trying to convert a project that uses more than one property sheet.

The solution is to create a dummy project in VS2008 with a single property sheet, and open that in VS2010 to convert it. Repeat that for all property sheets to get them to convert correctly. Close VS2010 after each conversion to "reset" it.

Also see here for a possible problem:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2262855

Answer (score 3):

Do you happen to still have the VS2005 property sheets? If you do, try importing them from the Property Manager window. For an example on how to do it, please visit the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z7t21ew.aspx)

The following link at MSDN may also help you

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/02/visual-studio-2010-c-project-upgrade-guide.aspx